# How can I build a query scope in Laravel that takes data if sum of relative table column is between requested range?

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent, scope

I have two tables loads and stops. The Stops table has a price column. Loads' price is equal to the sum of stops' price related to the load. I want to build a scope that builds a query to get all loads where it's the price is in the requested range.

My scope:

```
public function scopeBetweenPrice($query, $from, $to) {
    if ($from !== null || $to !== null) {
        return $query;
    }
    return $query;
}
```

Comment: You can just use [whereBetween](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#additional-where-clauses), that's basically all your scope would be doing anyways.

Comment: Can you give an example, please? I've no idea how to get the sum of stop prices within between method.